# Does order of BizAgi form actions have any effect on how they are executed ? If so, is there any way to rearrange them?

Tags: forms, validation, action, bizagi

I have a bizagi form and actions associated with it under actions and validations. Does the order in which these actions are specified affect the order in which they are executed ? For eg. I have radiobutton rdBtnType, if I have 'rdBtnType changes' and 'rdBtnType changes to ABC' actions specified, does the final outcome differ for

**rdBtnType changes**

**rdBtnType changes to ABC**

from

**rdBtnType changes to ABC**

**rdBtnType changes**

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the execution follows the action order.

This can be quite a big problem when you have complex forms with a lot of rules in it, which is why form modulation is so important in Bizagi.

Cheers